# Conditionally and interatively calculate column based on value of three columns

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, pandas, logic

I am running Windows 10, Python 2.7 through the Spyder IDE.

I have a pandas `DataFrame` called `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fld1': ['x', 'x', 'x','y','y','y','z','z']
                , 'fld2': ['x', 'y', 'z','x','y','z','x','y']
                , 'relationship': [.25,.25,.50,.33,.33,.33,.5,.5]})

df
 Out[172]: 
  fld1 fld2  relationship
 0    x    x          0.25
 1    x    y          0.25
 2    x    z          0.50
 3    y    x          0.33
 4    y    y          0.33
 5    y    z          0.33
 6    z    x          0.50
 7    z    y          0.50
```

I would like build a `function` that iterates over the rows of a `Dataframe` `df` to produce a new column in `df`.

This function would start by:

**Step 1:** take the `relationship` column where `fld1` = `x` and `fld2` = `x`  and then

**Step 2:** check to see if cases where `fld1` = `x` has any more unique values of `fld2`.

**Step 3:** If there is another unique value of `fld2` associated with `fld1` = `x` (in this two more unique values exist, `x` and `y`), add the `relationship` value from **Step 1** to the `relationship` column of `fld1` = `x` and the next unique value of `fld2` (in this example `fld2` = `y` is the next unique value) multiplied by the inverse of the relationship (in this case `fld1` = `y` and `fld2` = `x`)

**Step 4:** repeat **Step 2** until all unique values of `fld2` with `fld1` = `x` have been calculated in this way

**Step 4:** repeat **Step 1** for the next unique value of `fld1`. In this case it would be `fld1` = `y`

**To explain this function logic another way**, below is an example of how this would be done in `excel`:

```
        A       B         C             D
   1    fld1    fld2      relationship  Connection
   2    x        x         0.25         =C2+(C3*C5)+(C4*C8)
   3    x        y         0.25         =C3+(C4*C9)
   4    x        z         0.5          =C4+(C3*C7)
   5    y        x         0.33         =C5+(C7*C8)
   6    y        y         0.33         =C6+(C5*C3)+(C7*C9)
   7    y        z         0.33         =C7+(C5*C4)
   8    z        x         0.5          =C8+(C9*C5)
   9    z        y         0.5          =C9+(C8*C4)
```

The output of the function should product a `Dataframe` identical to `df2` below:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'fld1': ['x', 'x', 'x','y','y','y','z','z']
            , 'fld2': ['x', 'y', 'z','x','y','z','x','y']
            , 'relationship': [.25,.25,.50,.33,.33,.33,.5,.5]
            , 'connection':     [.5825,0.5,0.5825,0.495,0.5775,0.495,0.665,0.75]})

df2
Out[174]: 
    connection fld1 fld2  relationship
0      0.5825    x    x          0.25
1      0.5000    x    y          0.25
2      0.5825    x    z          0.50
3      0.4950    y    x          0.33
4      0.5775    y    y          0.33
5      0.4950    y    z          0.33
6      0.6650    z    x          0.50
7      0.7500    z    y          0.50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here it goes, this is one way of solving your problem.  I used a dictionary to hold the values for each combination.

```
xyzdict = {"xx":0.25,
          "xy":0.25,
          "xz":0.5,
          "yx":0.33,
          "yy":0.33,
          "yz":0.33,
          "zx":0.5,
          "zy":0.5}
```

Then, for each 'connection' combination, the first letter was always that same as the first letter for `fld1`.  the second letter was always `not` `fld1`.  So here is an exhaustive and maybe not pythonic way of calculating your values and storing the combinations' connections values in a dictionary for later use.

```
cnxn = {}
xyz = ["x","y","z"]

for combo in xyzdict.keys():
    #print "the combo is %s" % (combo) #xyzdict[two] #actual value
    first_letter = combo[0]

    not_second = [combo[0],combo[1]]
    not_second_letter = list(set(xyz) - set(not_second))

    if len(not_second_letter) > 1:
        multi_cnxn = []
        for each_not_second_letter in not_second_letter:

            fwd = ''.join((first_letter,each_not_second_letter))
            rev = ''.join((each_not_second_letter,first_letter))
            cnxnval = xyzdict[fwd] * xyzdict[rev]

            multi_cnxn.append(cnxnval)

        rowvalue = xyzdict[combo] + sum(multi_cnxn)
        cnxn[combo] =rowvalue
    else:
        fwd = ''.join((first_letter,not_second_letter[0]))
        rev = ''.join((not_second_letter[0],first_letter))
        cnxnval = xyzdict[fwd] * xyzdict[rev]

        rowvalue = xyzdict[combo] + cnxnval
        cnxn[combo] = rowvalue
```

Almost there, define a function `check` that will pull out your `fld1` and `fld2` and return the calculated values from `cnxn` above.

```
def check(fld1,fld2,cnxn_sub):
    rowpair = ''.join((fld1,fld2))
    return cnxn_sub[rowpair]
```

Finally, a little pandas `apply` to bring it all home.

```
df['connection'] = df.apply(lambda row: check(row['fld1'], row['fld2'],cnxn), axis=1)
```

Here are my results, our "yz" connection is a little off, idk if that is on your end or mine...

```
fld1    fld2    relationship    connection
0   x   x   0.25    0.5825
1   x   y   0.25    0.5000
2   x   z   0.50    0.5825
3   y   x   0.33    0.4950
4   y   y   0.33    0.5775
5   y   z   0.33    0.4125
6   z   x   0.50    0.6650
7   z   y   0.50    0.7500
```

Good Luck!

Comment: How I'm interpreting the problem is that your "yz" row from you excel example should read `=C7+(C5*C3)`

Comment: thanks for your effort here, I'm currently at a wedding, with no access to a laptop. I will evaluate your answer in a few days. Thanks again and I will be in touch!